Measure of hypergeometric integral
While reading Yoshida's book on Hypergeometric functions, I came across the following expression of hypergeometric integral -
$$ I(x) = \int_C \prod_{j=1}^4 (x_{1j}t_1+x_{2j}t_2)^{\beta_j} d \log \frac{x_{1p}t_1+x_{2p}t_2}{x_{1q}t_1+x_{2q}t_2}$$
where $t_1 : t_2$ are homogenous coordinates in $\mathbb{C}P1$, $1 \leq p \neq q \leq 4$ and -
$$\beta_1+\cdots+\beta_4=0$$
My question is, how to make sense of the measure of this integral? I tried to understand this by an analogy to the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$. If the measure on the 2d plane is $dx \wedge dy$, then it can be lifted to the unit circle by the following procedure -
$$(2xdx+2ydy) \wedge \omega = dx \wedge dy$$
where $\omega$ is the measure on the circle. The fact that the circle is defined in terms of an algebraic equation helps us here. But, in the case of the projective line, we as such do not have an equation, but instead a coordinate description $t_1 : t_2$. Is this the reason why a log factor comes up in the measure? Is it somehow related to variable change?
Also, the contour in the integration is a single contour, but we have two parameters in the measure, $t_1$ and $t_2$. How to interpret this?
Any help will be appreciated.

There was a small typo in the question which has now been fixed. Could anyone figure this out?

Anyone with anything?

Could anyone come up with anything?
